# Construct a quadrangulation with connectivity 2 and minimum degree 3

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

A **quadrangulation** is a simple graph(map) where every face is quadrilateral.

It is not difficult to find that minimum degree of any quadrangulation is no more than $3$. Furthermore, connectivity of any quadrangulation is between $2$ and $3$.

I want to find some quadrangulations  with  connectivity  $2$. It is easy to find when the minimum degree is $2$. For example: $K_{2,n-2}$.
[image]

However I have not found a quadrangulation with minimum degree $3$ and connectivity  $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SageMath with [plantri](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_generators.html#sage.graphs.graph_generators.GraphGenerators.quadrangulations), a tool written by [Brinkmann et. al](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/plantri/) to generate all quadrangulations up to isomorphism with the desired properties as follows

```
for n in range(1, 15):
    gen = graphs.quadrangulations(n, minimum_degree=3, minimum_connectivity=2)
    for g in gen:
        if g.vertex_connectivity() == 2:
            g.show()
```

Some printed graph look as follows

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reminding!  I just got inspired by following paper of the same author and constructed some graphs I want to get  based on separating  4-cycle. 
[Brinkmann, Gunnar, et al. "Generation of simple quadrangulations of the sphere." Discrete mathematics 305.1-3 (2005): 33-54.]

Comment: I used to work through the same paper. There are several more paper covering the tools plantri and geng including how they solved the graph isomorphism problem efficiently, which might be interesting to you as well if you want to work on that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. ￣︶￣